# How do I save data in an application scope in PHP?

Tags: php, scope, save

I'm a Java and C# developer, and, I admit, I'm not that good in PHP.

I need to store an object in an application scope that lives as long as the app itself is running. I can't save it in the Session, because it expires, also I can't serialize it to disk.

Is there something like a C# `Application` object in PHP?

Comment: Be aware that unlike in Java (and probably in C#), PHP code doesn't live on outside a page request. You will have to manually store it and retrieve it somewhere for every page -- however, this is easily put inside your framework to give the effect that it's "always available".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**2018 Edit:** Time has **not** been kind to APC, especially since PHP 7 includes bundled support for Zend Optimizer+, which does largely the same thing (except the key-store). These days, the key store aspect has been forked over into [the APCu project](https://github.com/krakjoe/apcu).

However, in 2018, the preferred key-store of choice is [**Redis**](https://redis.io/). See the [**ext-redis project**](https://github.com/phpredis/phpredis) for details.

---

PHP has an application scope of sorts.  it's called [**APC (Alternative PHP Cache)**](https://www.php.net/apc).

Data should be cached in APC if it meets the following criteria:

1. It is not user session-specific (if so, put in $_SESSION[])
2. It is not really long-term (if so, use the file system)
3. It is only needed on one PHP server (if not, consider using [**memcached**](https://www.php.net/manual/en/intro.memcached.php))
4. You want it available to every page of your site, instantly, even other (non-associated) PHP programs.
5. You do not mind that all the data stored in it is lost on Apache reload/restart.
6. You want data access far faster than file-based, memcached, or (esp.) database-based.

APC is installed on a great many hosts already, but follow the aforementioned guide to get installed on your box.  Then you do something like this:

```
if (apc_exists('app:app_level_data') !== false)
{
    $data = apc_fetch('app:app_level_data');
}
else
{
    $data = getFromDB('foo');
    apc_store('app:app_level_data', $data);
}
```

Comment: @daVe, except it wasn't. Now it is :-)