# make a GET request and send the last date in AJAX,php

Tags: php, ajax

So i made a get request for some data from my server. Now i am trying to make alaso a GET request and get the latest data from my server. I need to keep somewhere the latest date from the latest Get request .Can anyone help me?

Comment: well i only want to keep somewhere the latest date and actually make the get request after it. I don't actually know where to store the date and how.

Comment: when you say "date" you mean specific format? or a time() is enough, writing it to an INT(10) column?

Comment: time() is enough i think. i need only to send to the server and make the json for the latest data(select *from table where time=latestdatefromhtmlpage)

Comment: i am using ajax request on a html page and retrive a json data. i want that json data to be acording to the latest time.I have a messages table in my database and want to actually make requests to get the latest messages.

Comment: the reason for storing the time is for actually searching the latest data?

Comment: yes,all i want is to store the time and send it in the get link. to make the select from that date.

Comment: SELECT * FROM 'messages' ORDER BY time DESC LIMIT 1;    create an INT(10) column in 'messages' table and store time() for new inserted record in 'time'

Comment: messages.php?format=json&&date=12.03.2012

Comment: and i want to retrieve the latest messages. So in my html page i need to set the date in that link. First time i get the entire data then the second time i only get the messages from the last data.

Comment: i am only asking to save somewhere a date variable that is cached somewhere..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are using JSON. Just generate the actual date with PHP: getdate() (read the manual), and put it in your JSON object!

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you are looking for [How do I save data in an application scope in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3713311/how-do-i-save-data-in-an-application-scope-in-php)

Use this to save the date in application scope. So you get this the next time you make a call.