# Do multiple-user sessions exist in PHP?

Tags: php, apache, session, server-side

Is it possible to store values dynamically "in the server" in PHP? I mean, a session with variables that are accessible to every user.

For example, a variable ('$multipleUserVariable') that is increased by one every time a new user loads the page, like this:

```
session_start();
if (!isset($_SESSION['PHPSESSID']) {
    $multipleUserVariable++;
}
```

I'm almost sure the only way to do this is using a database, but still.

Thanks!

Comment: You are correct there's no such thing in PHP's built in library. Depending of your application scale you could use in memory database for faster access.

Comment: I am curious, when such a session expected to expire. And if never - why do you call it *a session* at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that's possible. Thats not the purpose of sessions.

You have many other options - any database, writing to filesystem or caching engine...

Comment: You're right, I guess a catching engine like memcached is the closest way to do what I'm trying to

Answer (score 3):

Please see following post : [Application scope in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531075/application-scope-in-php)

or google for PHP Application scope variables

Answer (score 1):

You could do this with semaphore or shared memory:

http://us.php.net/sem

http://www.phpdig.net/ref/rn57.html

http://www.re-cycledair.com/php-dark-arts-semaphores

Answer (score -4):

Such a "session" called *"a database"* and happily used on every site. Though do not have a word "session" in it's name because session belongs to single user, not all of them.

Comment: I was asking if there was a way to do that BESIDES using a database

Comment: I do answer sensible questions. So, I made one out of yours and answered it. Have a courage to face the harsh truth.