# Php storing timestamp in variable for later use

Tags: php, html, variables, timestamp

I am looking to use php to insert a tag into a webpage that will be picked up by a c# program. The code that I have thus far is as follows,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <body>

        <?php

             echo "<tag>Override on Pump 1 Authorised by ABC123 ";

             echo date(' h:i:s');

             echo "</tag>";

        ?>

        </body>
     </html>
```

So that the final output on the webpage is:

Override on Pump 1 Authorised by ABC123 10:35:56

However, as you would expect the TimeStamp keeps changing. I need a way so that when the tag is inserted into the HTML page, it is that date that is displayed.

For example, if i open the webpage and it's Override on Pump 1 Authorised by ABC123 10:35:56 then the next time I refresh it will be the same. It's possible PHP may not be the way forward for this, but the work needs to be done server side as the C# program will not read client-side (javascript) timestamps, it just reads the variable. Any help on this would be much appreciated! Thanks in advance :).

Answer (score 0):

Just use [sessions](http://www.tizag.com/phpT/phpsessions.php):

```
<?php
    session_start();

    // other code here

    // Save date in session
    $_SESSION['time'] = date(' h:i:s');

    // more code here
```

Then on the other pages you want to access it:

```
<?php
    session_start();
    echo $_SESSION['time'];
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply!

I've gave this a go, and it's not working as I need it to. Probably my explanation. The C# program will periodically check the webpage (every ten seconds) which is creating a new session and thus, the timestamp is different.

Comment: In that case you'll want to either write the value to a file on the hard drive or use a caching system  like memcache or APC

Comment: what about , storing this value in a file or in a database ?
Probably duplicated http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1531075/application-scope-in-php